# Does terrain provide a defense bonus?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

In the regular Fire Emblem games, characters will receive a bonus to defense when standing on certain types of terrain, such as forests. Does this system exist in Fire Emblem Heroes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 1.3.0, there are now defensive terrain bonuses for the defensive maps. According to [this article](https://nintendowire.com/news/2017/05/08/fire-emblem-heroes-gets-version-1-3-0-update/), these spaces reduce incoming damage by 30% of the unit's Def/Res.

> These new maps include defensive terrain. A Hero on a defensive terrain tile receives a damage reduction of 30% of their Def or Res.

For reference, this is what this terrain looks like in-game:

[image: Defensive terrain]

Answer (score 14):

There are no terrain bonuses in Fire Emblem Heroes.

The only affect the terrain has in this mobile game is for movement, below is a quick summary:

Standard unit movement:

```
Flyers: 2 spaces
Calvary: 3 spaces
Infantry: 2 spaces
Armoured: 1 space
```

The terrain affects the units accordingly:

- **Plains**: Movement is normal
- **Forest**: Does not affect Flyers or Armoured, Infantry take 2 units of movement to enter, Calvary cannot enter.
- **Mountain**: Only Flyers may enter
- **Water**: Only Flyers may enter
- **Walls**: No units may enter
  (which is also different from past FE games where Flyers could fly over)

Comment: I'm kinda going by memory, but I'm pretty sure that certain walls (particularly in "interior" maps) in certain past FE games did block flying units. That said, upvote for thorough and solid answer.

Comment: @Walt Oh for sure! You're correct that there are walls in the past games flyers can't go over, adding that would have just complicated my answer unnecessarily as the question is just for the new game :) just wanted to add that last part in as a tidbit

Answer (score 0):

In Heroes, Terrain only affects movement for non-flying units. They do not affect anything else in the battle. This is easily testable by going into any of the tree area during a battle.